# Как правильно подсчитать количество выделенных байт когда используется aligned выделение памяти?

Tags: c++, c

Есть вот это. 10 байт, выравнивание 1024.

```
_aligned_malloc( 10, 1024 );
```

Сколько выделится памяти? 10 * 1024?

Comment: от 10 до 1015 байт + возможный оверхед от аллокатора

Comment: *Выравнивание* — это всего лишь *задание младших битов адреса*. Почитайте, что ли, литературу.

Comment: @user7860670, с чего вы взяли? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019

Comment: *`"Use _aligned_free to deallocate memory obtained by both _aligned_malloc and _aligned_offset_malloc. Don't use free, which doesn't reclaim the aligned memory correctly and can lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs."`* -- я просто офигиваю от M$ (и зачем вы с ними связались?)

Answer (score 3):

Строго говоря *выделение* памяти и *выравнивание* ортогональны друг другу. В вашем примере *выравнивание* определено как 1024, то есть зануление младших 10 бит адреса. Например, для 32-битного адресного пространства это будет двоичное число `xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx00 0000 0000`. Размер выделяемой памяти зависит от алокатора, если используется напрямую тот, что даёт ядро операционной системы, то скорее всего выделится одна страница памяти (чаще всего 4096 байт), но и там не всё так просто. Ах да, если размер выделяемой памяти при заданном выравнивании не получается найти (в большинстве случаев из-за фрагментации), то вернётся код ошибки.

Более подробно по теме: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment и https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#ALLOCATION (увы, на русском быстро ничего хорошего не нашёл)

Answer (score 0):

В Linux (и м.б. в части остальных *nix-ов) для получения ответа на вопрос:

> *сколько памяти выделено вызовом функции из семейства `malloc()`?*

можно вызвать функцию [malloc_usable_size](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)

Простой эксперимент совпадает с ожиданиями и говорит, что не зависимо от запрошенного  выравнивания выделяется ближайшее большее чем запрошено разумное (с т.з. эффективности распределения памяти) количество.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
     
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *a = malloc(1);
  char *b = memalign(4096, 1);

  printf("alloc(1) usable: a (%p) = %d  aligned to 4096 b (%p) = %d\n",
     a, (int)malloc_usable_size(a), b, (int)malloc_usable_size(b));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Компилируем и смотрим:

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c && ./a.out
alloc(1) usable: a (0x5577e496f260) = 24  aligned to 4096 b (0x5577e4970000) = 24
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```